# Shortening javascript switch

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of code like this:

```
switch(v[0]){
    case 1:
        $(o).test({default:true}).on("click", function(e){
            stopf(e);
            func1(v[1]);}           
        });
        break;
    case 2:
        $(o).test({default:true}).on("click",function(e){
            stopf(e);
            func2(v[1]);}           
        });
        break;
    case 3:
        $(o).test({default:true}).on("click",function(e){
            stopf(e);
            func3();}       
        });
        break;
    case 4:
        $(o).test({default:true}).on("click",function(e){
            stopf(e);
            func4();}       
        });
        break;
    case 5:
        $(o).test({default:true}).on("click",function(e){
            stopf(e);
            func5(v[1],v[2]);}          
        });
        break;

    // AND ON AND ON....
}
```

As you can see the only difference is the `funcX()` part at the end of each line. Is there any way to shorten this code? Maybe something like this (tried it, doesn't work):

```
switch(v[0]){
    case 1: myfunc=func1(v[1]);break;
    case 2: myfunc=func2(v[1]);break;
    case 3: myfunc=func3();break;
    case 4: myfunc=func4();break;
    case 5: myfunc=func5(v[1],v[2]);break;
}
$(o).test({default:true}).on("click",function(e){
    stopf(e);
    myfunc);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If functions set on global scope, you can use:

```
$(o).test({
    default: true
}).on("click", function (e) {
    stopf(e);
    window["func" + v[0]](v[1], v[2]);
}
```

Comment: Look closer, he calls the function with different arguments in each case.

Comment: Awesome solution, but the case number 5 has v[1] and v[2].

Comment: @Barmar ya, just saw it

Comment: Please comment on downvote, what mistake i made? Should i remove answer?!

Comment: I think you assume too much about the argument list of the inner function. Seeing how erratic those are in the OTs example, who knows what might come in `// AND ON AND ON....`. Handling this with an ever growing ternary is just pure hell.

Comment: @Yoshi "I think you assume to much about the argument list of the inner function" Ya, i get your point!

Comment: I like this a lot. It works like a charm, and passing the entire array `v` just makes it even shorter. Thanks a lot, saves a lot of space.

Comment: @Michel glad that helps you but you should reconsider Barmar's answer and Yoshi's comment. BTW, 'space' taking by code shouldn't be much a concern here, readability/potability is much important imho

Comment: I can't see how this will work. V[1] might always be defined which makes it run with v[1] as a parameter, even in func3 and func4.

Comment: @MrX you can pass extra param to function, that's not really an issue even it could be one in some specific cases. But if func3 and func4 have no param defined, that's not an issue

Comment: @fzzle "But if func3 and func4 have no param defined" I'm just guessing because OP didn't pass it any param. So if he checks in some way inside this function for default param, passing null or maybe better undefined would still work anyway

Answer (score 3):

Put the functions in an object:

```
var funcs = {
    1: function() { func1(v[1]); },
    2: function() { func2(v[1]); },
    3: func3,
    4: func4,
    5: function() { funct5(v[1], v[2]); }
};
```

Then use this when binding the click handler:

```
$(o).test({default: true}).on("click", function(e) {
    stopf(e);
    funcs[v[0]]();
});
```

Notice that you have to wrap all the calls with `function() { ... }`. Otherwise, you'll call the function when you're assigning the variable, not when the event is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

If those parameters are important, this should make A. Wolff's work more properly:

```
$(o).test({default:true}).on("click",function(e){stopf(e);
    window["func" + v[0]](v[0] == (1 && 2 && 5) ? v[1] : null, v[0] == 5 ? v[2] : null);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eighter you have to declare it as an inline function:

```
switch(v[0]){
    case 1: myfunc=function(v[1]){ /* do something 1 */ }; break;
    case 2: myfunc=function(v[1]){ /* do something 2 */ }; break;
    case 3: myfunc=function(){ /* do something 3 */ }; break;
    case 4: myfunc=function(){ /* do something 4 */ }; break;
    case 5: myfunc=function(v[1],v[2]){ /* do something 5 */ }; break;
}
```

or you declare them first (seems like you already have the functions) and in my opinion this is more readable:

```
var func1 = function(p){ /* do something 1 */ };
var func2 = function(p,q){ /* do something 2 */ };

// and use the switch statement like this:

switch(v[0]){
  case 1: myfunc=func1; break;
  case 2: myfunc=func2; break;
}
```